# Future Continuous with planned actions?

Tags: future-tense, progressive-aspect, continuous

Does the Future Continuous create the idea of a planned action as well as the Present Continuous does?

If I say "I am seeing Jim tomorrow." I think it means that I have arranged it.

It's also OK to say "I will be seeing Jim tomorrow." Does it mean that the action has been planned?

On the other hand, I could say "I think I will see Jim tomorrow."

So, is it planned or spontaneous? If it's planned, how does it differ from the Present Continuous?

Comment: "I think I will see Jim tomorrow" could mean *I **expect** to see him* (simply because I know or think he will be at the same place as me, so our paths may well cross). Or it could mean *I have [just] [tentatively] decided that I **will** seek him out*. As ever, context is all.

Answer (score 4):

Like words, grammatical constructions often have overlapping meaning -synonymy- in some contexts but entirely different meanings in others.

In this particular context there is no significant difference between the constructions. Both contrast with the "simple future" *I will see Jim tomorrow*. The simple construction announces an intention of meeting, the two progressive (continuous) constructions add to this the implication that the meeting has already been scheduled.

To find a difference in meaning you have to look at **other contexts**. For instance, these two mean quite different things:

1. I am seeing Jim from time to time.
2. I will be seeing Jim from time to time.

The first describes a current arrangement which may or may not be expected to continue into the future; the second describes a future arrangement which may or may not have started already.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto StoneyB.

Let me add that whether any of your examples conveys planning or intention depends on context. Grammatically, I would say that they convey expectation.

For example, "I am being shot at sunrise tomorrow." I probably didn't plan that. I suppose someone planned it.

"The sun will be rising at 6:52 am." I don't think anyone particularly "planned" that, that's just how it is. Unless you're thinking in terms of God planning it.

Comment: Yes, but to my mind there would be something decidedly odd about saying "The sun **is** rising at 6:52 am tomorrow." It seems to me that explicit future tense *will be rising* works for "passive expectation", but (grammatically, at least) present tense *is rising* implies ***intention on the part of the sun***. Which is why it sounds weird.

Comment: But I have often heard people say, "Sunrise tomorrow is at 6:52 am" (or whatever time). That never sounded odd to me.

Comment: I think that's a significantly different construction (equivalent to perhaps *Sunrise **happens** tomorrow at 6:52*), which conveys no implication of "intentionality" on the part of "sunrise".